# Replacing GL_QUADS with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS results in graphical glitches

Tags: opengl

Just did my first attempt on replacing gl_quads with gl_triangle_strips and resulted in absolute failure :-(.

What's the difference between this :

```
//STRIPS (not working)
float v[] = {x,y,x,y+h,x+w,y,x+w,y+h};
float u[] = {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};

//STRIPS METHOD #2 as recommended (not 100% correct)
float v[] = {x,y,x+w,y,x,y+h,x+w,y+h};
float u[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1};
```

Versus this one that works :

```
//QUADS (works)
float v[] = {x,y,x+w,y,x+w,y+h,x,y+h};
float u[] = {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1};
```

???

EDIT
Screenshot showing the problem :

[image]

Comment: Use `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of strip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you swap the 2nd and 3rd coords? They look left-handed winding to me. Also, "absolute failure" would nicely be substantiated by screenshots. :)

Comment: Correct! The strips are CW while the quad is CCW

Comment: Thanks , that improved the rendering , although its still glitchy.Here's a screenshot of the problem : http://i44.tinypic.com/901tol.png

Answer (score 1):

> So i would like to kindly ask opengl experts what's the difference between this :

The difference is that triangle strip doesn't insert any "breaks" between primitives.

I.e. if GL_QUADS produce this:

```
0-2 4-6
| | | |
1-3 5-7
```

GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP will produce this:

```
0-2-4-6
|/|/|/|
1-3-5-7
```

So you can't draw multiple separated quads in one glBegin/glEnd call (well, you could insert degraded triangles after each quad, but that isn't a good solution, imo).

Comment: That makes sense now because i noticed that it renders fine a single object. Regarding the "degraded triangles" , could you elaborate a little more ..please ?

Comment: Ok i figured what you meant with "degenerate" triangles and its still faster than sending triangles for example :D